# two media queries are mixing with same declaration except one is ipad and other is desktop

Tags: html, css

I have two media queries and they both are being used in a bulleted list li tag. The problem is they clear every nth-child(2n+1) and nth-child(3n+1) being done but both are being used on the same page when debugging in chrome device views. So the grid is crooked and breaks every 2n+1 and every 3n+1. I've tried to re-order the queries but I still am not getting the result I want. This is happening in the portrait view.

```
@media only screen
and (min-width: 768px)
and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #products-list li:nth-child(3n+1) {     
        clear: left;
    }   
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    #products-list li:nth-child(2n+1) {     
        clear: left;
    }   
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    #products-list li:nth-child(3n+1) {     
        clear: left ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: One option would be to use @media (pointer:coarse) to detect touch input. Not sure if this is appropriate for your usecase.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question though, what is the result you are after? Keep in mind you're only querying the width of the screen, not the height, which could be what's getting you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse what your three separate code block do.

**First block** (Match `portrait` and `landscape`): Clears `3n+1`.

**Second block** (Match only `portrait`): Clears `2n+1`.

**Third block**(Match only `landscape`): Clears `3n+1`.

If you noticed, the first code block already done all the work of the third code block as its condition matches all both `portrait` and `landscape` orientation, thus producing the undesired result.

What you can do here to prevent execution overlapping is explicitly state this code applies to specifically which elements. You can nest media queries too.

```
@media only screen
and (min-width: 768px)
and (max-width: 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    @media only screen and (orientation : portrait){
        #products-list li:nth-child(2n+1) {     
            clear: left;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (orientation : landscape){
        #products-list li:nth-child(3n+1) {     
            clear: left;
        }
    }
}
```

Another simpler but bulkier way is that you remove the first code block, leaving only the following:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    #products-list li:nth-child(2n+1) {     
        clear: left;
    }   
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

    #products-list li:nth-child(3n+1) {     
        clear: left ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had to end up declaring both types of nth-child in each css declaration so you wrong

Comment: But did it solve your problem? Anyway, not sure about what you meant by "declaring both types of nth-child". The codes are copied directly from your code.